# Change RecyclerView Contents After Clicking On an Item in a DropDown Menu

Tags: java, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have two containers in my home activity, one is *Top Bar Fragment Container* and the other is *ViewPagers Container*. *Top Bar Fragment Container* consist of only one fragment which is the Top Bar Fragment (allows the user to pick a tag) while Viewpagers consists of 2 fragment which in each fragments they have a recycler view to display the posts with the selected tags on Top Bar Fragment.

What im trying to achieve is that when an item is clicked on the Top Bar Fragment, it gets the value to text then sends it to the Activity using an Interface and later on Fragment Viewpagers will get that value from the activity and set the firebase query in accordance with the text passed.

So far, the fragments are doing fine sending data to each other using interfaces. However, adapters only listens once, when view is created and not when data is passed from Fragments. How do I update the adapters after sending in data from Top Bar Fragment?

Here is my ViewPagerFragment(RecyclerView):

```
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions options, options2;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Question, QuestionsViewHolder> adapter;

     <!---- oncreate Code---->

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String ChosenTag = tvtest.getText().toString();

        if (text.equals("")){
            Query query = questionReference.orderByChild("location").equalTo("jakarta");


            options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Question>()
                            .setQuery(query, Question.class)
                            .build();

            adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Question, QuestionsViewHolder>(options) {

                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull QuestionsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Question model) {
                    holder.username.setText(model.getUsername());
                }

                @NonNull
                @Override
                public  QuestionsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.snippet_card_question_new, viewGroup, false);
                    QuestionsViewHolder viewHolder = new QuestionsViewHolder(view);
                    return viewHolder;
                }
            };

            qListRv.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.startListening();
        } else {

            Query query = questionReference.orderByChild("tags").equalTo(ChosenTag);

            options2 = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Question>()
                    .setQuery(query, Question.class)
                    .build();
            adapter.updateOptions(options2);
        }
    }
```

To put it simply, if user has not chosen on the TopBarFragment then text is returning a null, adapter will then query on the current location of the user. Else if user chose a tag on the Top Bar Fragment, Top Bar Fragment then sends the tag to string, updates the *String* ChosenTag, then adapter will then update its options to *options2*, which queries on the chosen tag.

I am not able to refresh my recyclerview after choosing. Yet interfaces work fine. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've searched everywhere and it seems like none could help me out, so here is what i've done and this worked for me. Hope this helps.

**I changed the Fragment B (TopBarFragment) to an Activity (TopBarActivity)**

The reason why i changed the fragment to an activity is because i wanted the whole RecyclerView Adapters to stop listening whenever a user is directed to the TopBar Activity. This way i can initiate a new adapter upon returning to the Activity that holds the RecyclerViews.

**The Plan**

1. Make two sets of Adapters (one for defaultAdapter, the other for
   what the user click on TopBarActivity. let's call it
   menuItemAdapter).
2. Extras to send strings from TopBarActivity upon user clicks to MainActivity. From then Fragments will check the Strings of the
   MainActivity.
3. Create two override methods (onPause & onResume), to either stop listening to the adapters, or start listening to them. We will
   create conditions here to either listen to default adapters or
   listen to what the user clicks. These Conditions will check if
   Strings on point 2 exist or not. If it exists then listen to
   menuItemAdapter else if strings does not exist, then listen to
   defaultAdapters.

**TopBarActivity Code**

```
             @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_top_bar); 

              //I am using Recycler view to display the  menu item lists on this activity.
             //RecyclerView Codes goes here

                    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                            i.putExtra("CHOSENITEM", (model.getItemName()));
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                 }
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private String choicesName = "";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

            setupTopBarStringListener();
    }

    private void setupTopBarStringListener() {
        choicesName = getIntent().getStringExtra("CHOSENITEM");
    }

    public String ChoicesString() {
        return choicesName;
    }
}
```

*String ChoicesString()* will then be called later on in Fragment A

**Fragment A Code**

```
    public class QuestionFragment extends Fragment {
    private String myStringFromActivity;
    RecyclerView contentListRv;
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions options, newoptions;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostsViewHolder> adapter, newadapters;


        @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onViewCreated: restart");


        contentListRv= view.findViewById(R.id.contentListRv);
        contentListRv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        HomeActivity activity = (HomeActivity) getActivity();
        myStringFromActivity = activity.ChoicesString();
        Log.i(TAG, "choices from activity= " + myStringFromActivity);

    }
 }
```

**Add Default Recyclers to Fragment A**

```
    public void setupRecyclers() {

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dschild : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String location = "" + dschild.child("location").getValue();

                Query query = questionReference.orderByChild("location").equalTo(location);


                options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Question>()
                        .setQuery(query, Post.class)
                        .build();

                adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostsViewHolder>(options) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Question model) {

                       holder.username.setText(model.getUsername());

                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public QuestionsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.snippet_posts_view, viewGroup, false);
                        PostsViewHolder viewHolder = new PostsViewHolder(view);
                        return viewHolder;
                    }

                };
                contentListRV.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.startListening();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

}
```

**Then add menuItem Recyclers to Fragment A**

```
    public void menuItemRecyclers() {

                Query query2 = questionReference.orderByChild("tags").equalTo(myStringFromActivity);


                newoptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Question>()
                        .setQuery(query2, Post.class)
                        .build();

                newadapters = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostsViewHolder>(options) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Question model) {

                       holder.username.setText(model.getUsername());

                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public QuestionsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.snippet_posts_view, viewGroup, false);
                        PostsViewHolder viewHolder = new PostsViewHolder(view);
                        return viewHolder;
                    }

                };
                contentListRV.setAdapter(newadapters);
                newadapters.startListening();
            }
        }
}
```

The code above shows that the String *myStringFromActivity* retrieved from MainActivity will be our query for the new Adapters.

Finally, we implement the onPause and onResume Methods to our Fragment A

```
    @Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i(TAG, "onStop: adapter stopped");
    if(myStringFromActivity== null){
        adapter.stopListening();
    } else {
        newadapters.stopListening();
    }

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(myStringFromActivity==null){
        setupRecyclers();
        Log.e(TAG, "onResume: String null" );
    }else{
        menuItemRecyclers();
    }
}
```

Code above shows that if we String *myStringFromActivity* is null (user hasn't clicked on any items in our Topbaractivity, then it runs the default Recyclers. Else if the user picked on an item then it runs the menuItemRecyclers (based on what the user chooses).

I am still open to better implementation regarding this one. Hope this helps!